# How to change the location of the “Clear all” button (Windows 10 Action Center)?

Tags: windows-10, user-interface, action-center

I have 2 computers with Windows 10. On one computer, the “Clear all” button of the Action Center is at the bottom right of the action center window. One the other one, it is at the top right of the window. How to change the location of this button? I want to have it on bottom right like on the other computer.

Comment: I believe Microsoft moved it with the latest upgrade.

Comment: You should verify both installations of Windows 10 are running identical versions of Windows 10.  You should also verify the exact build each installation is on.  Update your question with this information and I will submit my answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Before Windows 10 1709, all version of Windows 10 "Clear all" button is on the top right of the window. On Windows 10 1709, it's on bottom of the window.

[image]